# why Auth::user() is null in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've created a web.php route like this :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web' , 'auth']], function () {
    Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')->prefix('dashboard')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/index', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard.index');
    });
});
```

but in the `DashboardController > index()` `Auth::user()` return null.

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        dd(Auth::user());
        return view('panel.admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

in the `LoginController > login()` after `Auth::attempt($credentials)` the `Auth::user()` is correct.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login (AdminLoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('phone', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) 
        {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.index') ;
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['msg' => 'invalid inputs']);
    }
}
```

As I understand, most commonly mistakes are retrieving user from controller and absence of web middleware. And I'am consider it.

what is missing ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Not only it should be `web`, but `web` middleware should have `StartSession`: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/d39fb35b4d1192e434b77240547c9a0896aae7e2/app/Http/Kernel.php#L35. See if you don't have a middleware (share what you have in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file)

Comment: Try to print and check session data after login and before redireting to dashboard  with dd(session()->all());

Comment: web middleware already have StartSession, @matiaslauriti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me: I had to fix this by going into my config/auth.php and set the 'guard' => 'web'. (it was web before)

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```